# Add text after semicolon in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e, comments

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}
  Set $a = 10$\;  // \textit{$a$ denotes the amount of money}
  Decrease $a$ by $1$\;
\end{algorithm*}
\end{document}
```

The comment "$a$ denotes the amount of money" appears in the second line. I want it to appear in the first line. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can fudge it [like this](https://pastebin.com/raw/U3qVjdAD). Effectively using `;` explicitly to denote the end of a statement and then ``\\`` to break to the next line instead of `\;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `algorithm2e` provides the commands `\tcc` and `\tcp` to create multi-line and single line C-style comments respectively.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
    
\usepackage{xcolor}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm*}
Set $a = 10$; \tcp*{\itshape $a$ denotes the amount of money}
Decrease $a$ by $1$\;   
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

You may find it convenient to define a common style for all your Comments.

To do this, define a new command with one argument and include the formatting you want to apply to the Comment text.

Then define the style with `\SetCommentSty{<command name>}` (whithout `\`).

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{xcolor} 

\newcommand\newCommStyle[1]{\itshape\textcolor{blue}{#1}} % command to format the Comments <<<<<<
\SetCommentSty{newCommStyle}    % define the Comment style

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm*}
Set $a = 10$; \tcp*{$a$ denotes the amount of money}
Decrease $a$ by $1$\;   
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```